# How to show form region button on my ribbon in VSTO outlook C#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I have created a form using form region which takes user input using VSTO outlook C#.
The button which opens this form is located near Message button as shown in the image :

[image: Button service desk showed near message]

I want this button in my custom ribbon (eg. MY DESK -> Service Desk) that I already developed

Is it possible to move this button to the ribbon that I want?

Comment: why down vote ?? I think lot of people facing this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Eugene, your answer gave me hint to solve my problem

First I open new mail with code :

```
Application oApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        NameSpace oNs = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        MAPIFolder oInbox = oNs.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        Items oItems = oInbox.Items;
        MailItem oForm = oItems.Add("IPM.Note");
        oForm.Display(false);
```

And then instead of "GetInspector" I used "ActiveInspector()" and set it with my class name

`"oApp.ActiveInspector().SetCurrentFormPage("NameSpace.ClassName");"`

The complete code on button click:

```
private void btnOpenMailForm_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Application oApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        NameSpace oNs = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        MAPIFolder oInbox = oNs.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        Items oItems = oInbox.Items;
        MailItem oForm = oItems.Add("IPM.Note");
        oForm.Display(false);  
        oApp.ActiveInspector().SetCurrentFormPage("NameSpace.ClassName");
    }
```

This opens my custom outlook form from the button click of ribbon button.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ribbon UI in your add-in where you can repeat the built-in controls by specifying their `idMso`. VSTO provides two possible ways for customizing the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI):

- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019)
- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019)

To find control IDs you may download [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745). Also, you may check them in Outlook by navigating to the `Customize ribbon` page and looking at the popping out hints.

Also, you may place a custom ribbon control anywhere and call the following code to display your custom UI:

```
myitem.GetInspector.SetCurrentFormPage("Namespace.FormRegionClass")
```

The name used in [SetCurrentFormPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.setcurrentformpage) should be full class name for your custom region.